# grade input program python if else elif

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this grade input program. I need to input the grades between 0.6 to 1.0 and assign them a letter value. I can only use the if else method as we haven't gotten to the other methods yet in class...

```
score = raw_input("Enter Score Grade:")
sco = int(float(score))
if score < 0.60:
        print "Your grade is an F"
elif score >= 0.6:
        print "grade d"
elif score >= 0.7:
        print "grade c"
elif score >= 0.8:
        print "grade b"
elif score >= 0.9:
        print "grade a" 
else:
        print "wrong score"`
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to go highest to lowest score, you can also do this:

```
score = float(raw_input("Enter Score Grade:"))
if score < 0.60:
    print "Your grade is an F"
elif score < 0.7:
    print "grade d"
elif score < 0.8:
    print "grade c"
elif score < 0.9:
    print "grade b" 
elif score <= 1.0:
    print "grade a"
else:
    print "wrong score"
```

---

If you do decide to check from highest to lowest, being consistent is a good practice. You can check your failing grade last:

```
score = float(raw_input("Enter Score Grade:"))
if score > 1:
    print "wrong score"
elif score >= 0.9:
    print "grade a"
elif score >= 0.8:
    print "grade b"
elif score >= 0.7:
    print "grade c"
elif score >= 0.6:
    print "grade d"
else:
    print "Your grade is an F"
```

---

As a reusable function :

```
def grade(score):
    if score > 1:
        return "wrong score"
    if score >= 0.9:
        return "grade a"
    if score >= 0.8:
        return "grade b"
    if score >= 0.7:
        return "grade c"
    if score >= 0.6:
        return "grade d"
    return "Your grade is an F"

score = float(raw_input("Enter Score Grade:"))
print grade(score)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should start from the largest grade first:
as you see `0.92 > 0.6` and also `0.92 > 0.9`
But according to yout logic,  it will satisfy the first `if` and will never reach last `if`.
Do something like this:

```
score = raw_input("Enter Score Grade:")
sco = int(float(score))
if score < 0.60:
    print ("Your grade is an F")
elif score >= 0.9:
    print ("grade a")
elif score >= 0.8:
    print ("grade b")
elif score >= 0.7:
    print ("grade c")
elif score >= 0.6:
    print ("grade d") 

else:
    print ("wrong score")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go from high grade to low grade. You need to change `sco = int(float(score))` to `score = float(score)`. It is not required to change it to `int` as you are comparing `float`

```
score = raw_input('Enter the Score')
score = float(score)

if score >= 0.9:
    grade = 'A'
elif score >= 0.8:
    grade = 'B'
elif score >= 0.7:
    grade = 'C'
elif score >= 0.6:
    grade = 'D'
else:
    grade = 'F'
print 'Your Grade : ' + grade
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take not of the first condition. If the first condition is equal to 0.9, it will equate to false and give the grade of 'B'. Also, it will be wise to convert the input to int first

```
score = int(raw_input('Enter the Score'))
score = float(score)

if score > 0.9:
    grade = 'A'
elif score >= 0.8:
    grade = 'B'
elif score >= 0.7:
    grade = 'C'
elif score >= 0.6:
    grade = 'D'
else:
    grade = 'F'
print 'Your Grade : ' + grade
```

It is therefore advisable to use the greater than or equal to so as to handle the situation when it is equal to the upper value(ie 0.9).

```
score = int(raw_input('Enter the Score'))
score = float(score)

if score >= 0.9:
    grade = 'A'
elif score >= 0.8:
    grade = 'B'
elif score >= 0.7:
    grade = 'C'
elif score >= 0.6:
    grade = 'D'
else:
    grade = 'F'
print 'Your Grade : ' + grade
```